# Is wait set a part of the monitor or are they two separate things?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

So i'm trying to understand monitors in java and I came across two new concepts which are object headers and the wait-set.

My question is does the concept of the monitor correspond to a explicit implementation like in terms of code, which is in itself separate from wait set or any other synchronization feature for that matter.

Or is it a concept that encompasses or includes different features such as the wait set feature and locks? so basically what I'm asking is, is the monitor simply a name given to a group of features that control thread access and behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The authors of the Java language consider locks as a part of monitor and wait set as a separate concept (see [JLS chapter 17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html)).
On the other hand, wait set is tightly coupled with monitor, so thinking of wait set as a part of monitor is no harm.

Comment: So what you are saying is that monitors are just a groups of features that facilitate synchronization, in that sense locks and as you mentioned wait set can be grouped under the term monitor.

Comment: Yes, Wikipedia considers monitor as a mutex plus wait set.